# Funny behavior when using text-align: center on a textarea in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, textarea, center, text-align

I've created a textarea element, and applied a style of text-align: center; to it. Now, whenever I type something and then press enter to go to a new line, the text on the previous line will be bumped over the left a little. Why is this happening? I've tested this in Firefox, and the problem is not present. It is present in Internet Explorer 8 and 9. Any ideas?

SOLVED: I found that adding a css style of white-space: pre; to the text area fixes the problem.

Comment: it sounds like IE is calculating the newline character.  it's going to be a hard one to solve in a textarea box but im sure someone will figure out the answer. bunch of smart cookies around here :)

Comment: Might want to put a 1ex or 2ex left padding for that element if on MSIE.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried adding left padding of 1ex like Jay suggested, and that shifted ALL the text over a little, not just the line I'm on, so the problem is still happening.